# cannot find opencv_traincascade in openCV

Tags: .net, opencv

I installed [openCV 2.4.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.3/) and tried to find opencv_traincascade.exe to train the classifier. However, I can only find C:\opencv\apps\traincascade with some C++ files.
Do I need to do something to get opencv_traincascade.exe?
I am using Visual Studio 2012 and windows 8.

Comment: you can compile the `traincascade.cpp` file

Comment: try to run cmake in that dir to generate a vs solution/cvproj